# How to remove strange big margin around pages in firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

[image: hackaday page in firefox with white margine.]
Recently in firefox, I have strange margin around the page.
What firefox settings responsible for this? And how to remove this margins.

Comment: Have you used firefox's dev tools recently? They should have an option that lets you change the shape of the viewport to match the viewport of different common devices, useful when testing a page's responsive design.

Comment: Have you customized any of your windows Accent Colour using a registry hack or tweak tool?  If so, could be this issue https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1524515#c9

Comment: It's running on debian linux, no registry hacks as I trough. Maybe it's something with dev tools, maybe I accidentally changed something there.

Comment: You could save your bookmarks, uninstall Firefox completely and re-install. This should get rid of any unintended settings.

Comment: It looks like you have quite a few addons which might modify your browser. Try to go to help->troubleshoot mode. This will start firefox without addons. If your problem disappears, disable your addons one by one until you find the culprit

Comment: No it doesn't help. Even without addons that strange margin is still present.

Comment: Have you got any themes installed? Go to `about:addons` -> themes, and disable any installed themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by having this setting enabled: `privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing`. Go to your Firefox profile folder, open "user.js" and "prefs.js" files and delete the following line:

```js
    user_pref("privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing", true);
```

To open your profile folder: Type `about:support` in the address bar, find  "Profile Folder" in the table and click on "Open Folder".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find any solution to the problem, a strong method is to
save your bookmarks, uninstall Firefox completely,clean up all its folders
and re-install it.

This should get rid of any unintended settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check your zoom, you may have jostled it:

> You can reset the page zoom on pages that cause problems.
> View > Zoom > Reset (Ctrl+0 (zero); Command+0 on Mac)
> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Zoom_text_of_web_pages

(from [a Support thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967080))

Comment: I checked the zoom at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it could happen accidentaly, but probably there's some wrong information in your `userChrome.css` file, which is [a "Master CSS File" Firefox offers](https://www.userchrome.org/) for any webpages:

- open your Firefox profile folder: Go to the URL `about:support`, scroll down to "Profile Folder", click on "open Folder. Explorer will open
- Go to the `chrome` subdirectory
- make a backup of the `userChrome.css` just in case
- open the `userChrome.css` file with any text editor, delete any content, and save the file

This should reset any global styling.

NOTE // Second solution:

> By default, userChrome.css modifications are disabled in Firefox. You need to make sure that on the `about:config` page in Firefox, the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` preference is set to `true` and then restart the browser.
> ([copied from the mozilla support pages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1325862))

So, a second solution would be to set the above flag to false.

Comment: In the first solution I just don't find userChrome.css at all. Second solution not worked for me. In the end I just rpurge firefox and remove all firefox directories and reinstall it and it fixes all.

Comment: In the first solution, there was no chrome subdirectory at all.